# Prevent user from going back to previous page after logout without disabling back button on browser with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a simple login and logout for my homework, I am using $_SESSION to show the username from database  of the currently logged in user. Login and logout is working but when back button of the browser is pressed it will go back to my previous page where I logged out. Because it was already session_destroy when I logged out it would output an error as back button was pressed.

Tried disabling the back button but doesn't look good, user might think webpage is broken

samp.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['botLogin']))
  {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'db_name';

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col_userName = '$username' AND col_custPass = '$password' ");

      if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)
      {
        $_SESSION['session_var_user'] = $username;
        header('Location:samp2.php');
      }
      else
      {
        echo "Username or password mismatch";
      }
  }
?>

<form action = "samp.php" method="post">
      <input type = "text" name = "username" placeholder="username">     
      <input type = "text" name = "password" placeholder="password">     
      <input type = "submit" name = "botLogin" value = "login">    
</form>
```

samp2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "Hi," . $_SESSION['session_var_user'];

if(isset($_POST['logout']))
  {
    session_destroy();
    echo "<script>location.href='samp.php';</script>";         
  }
?>

<form action = "samp2.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout">
</form>
```

If I logged out is it possible when back button is pressed it will just direct me to login page again instead of directing me to previous page?

error when back button button is pressed after logging out:

> Notice: Undefined index: session_var_user in C:\xampp\htdocs\name\samp2.php on line 4
>       Hi,

Comment: You could redirect them `if(empty($_SESSION['session_var_user'])) { header(...)`. You should hash your user's passwords and parameterize that query. It is sql injectible and with plain text passwords it a big security flaw.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for answering mr. cg . I just created a different login page without navbar and even I pressed the back button it won't show the error undefined index and it will just return to login page.

process of loggin it

```
if($row['col_userName'] == $username AND $row['col_custPass'] = $password){
     $_SESSION['session_var_user'] = $username; // I created the session variable 
    echo "
            <script> 
              window.location.href = 'index.php';
            </script>
        ";
    }else{echo "failed";}
```

code in navbar

```
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class = "justtextstyle" href="#">
            <?php 
               if(!isset($_SESSION['session_variable']))
               {
                   echo "<a class = 'justtextstyle' href='login.php'>Log In Here</a>";
               }
               else
               {
                   echo "Hi," . $_SESSION['session_variable'];
               }
           ?>
        </a>
    </li>
```

the code in my question is different but same idea because that was the experimental php file and this was my actual assignment. I always make experimental file first coz i don't wanna mess with the original file lol.

or try to put this in navbar, indicating that if the session is not set it will redirect to index because session will only be set after successful login and if you logout the session would unset even if you press back button it will not go back to your previous page because session is still unset.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, in samp2.php replace the 'session_start();' with the below code

> ```
> if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
> session_start(); }
> if (isset($_SESSION['session_var_user'])) { }
> else {
> header("Location: /samp.php/"); }
> ```

This code will check if the session does exist, if it does not, it will redirect the user to the login page